# How to create mock test of following method

Tags: java, mocking, mockito, apache-zookeeper, powermock

I have created an application in which i have used asyncronous api of zookeeper. I am not able to write mock test of following method.

```
public static void createAssignNode(String path, long endPointer) {
        zk.create(path, Bytes.toBytes(endPointer),
                ZooDefs.Ids.OPEN_ACL_UNSAFE, CreateMode.PERSISTENT,assignTaskWorkerCallback,endPointer);
}

static AsyncCallback.StringCallback assignTaskWorkerCallback = new AsyncCallback.StringCallback() {
    public void processResult(int resultCode, String path, Object endPointer, String name) {
        switch (KeeperException.Code.get(resultCode)) {
            case CONNECTIONLOSS:
                LOG.error("Connection Loss");
                throw new IllegalStateException();
            case OK:
                LOG.info("My created task name: " + name);
                break;
            default:
                LOG.error("Something went wrong" + KeeperException.create(KeeperException.Code.get(resultCode), path));
        }
    }
};
```

I read about how to write mock test cases a lot but still facing problem in writing mock test of above method.

I am writing mock test for the first time

Comment: And you want to test what exactly?

Comment: test if above method is working properly

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To write a test you first need to know what behaviour you are trying to test. If you cannot concisely describe the behaviour you are testing then you won't be able to write a concise test case.

The only part of this code that seems suitable for testing with a mock is testing that you register your callback with zookeeper. To test this you'd need to inject a mock zookeeper instance into your zk variable. That might be tricky with your current design because you've made it a static. If zk was an instance member injected in the constructor then you'd easily be able to replace it with a mock object in the test case.

Comment: Suppose if zk is an instance variable, then how will I write test case. I am confused because of asyncronous api of zookeeper.

Comment: Again it comes back to the question if what you are trying to test. It sounds like you are trying to test zookeeper, leave that job to the zookeeper developers. All you can really test with a mock is that you call the zookeeper api correctly, so if you inject a mock you can verify you are calling the create method with the parameters you expect.

Comment: Got it. Thanks for answering my question so patiently.